# What is the breakdown of federated login provider usage across the network?

Tags: discussion, login

(for bonus points... how does this compare to traditional email/password signup?)

We find on our site, over 48% are represented by facebook and 29% represented by google. We're thinking about dropping support for the under-utilised ones.

Comment: Are you asking about stackoverflow?  Or is this a question that belongs somewhere other than meta?

Comment: Good question. I think the answer is mostly Google, because a lot of our traffic comes from there. FYI, the StackExchange network does not have its own proprietary authentication system -- the choices are anonymous or using an OpenID, and that's it.